# How to set m parameter of clusterR function in R?

Tags: raster, r, clustering

I want to manage a clustered computation on raster and thus use the "clusterR" function in R (package 'raster').
However, there's a tuning m parameter to set, but the only explanation about this parameter is

> m : tuning parameter to determine how many blocks should be used. The number is rounded and multiplied with the number of nodes.

But which value must be associated to this parameter ? How to decide it ?

Comment: You can use `system.time()` function to assess performance with different values of `m` to find out which value is more appropriate for your system.

Comment: ok but i'm using this clustering in many different situation and I don't "want" to define by trials&error the best value... any idea to find the "good parameter" knowing the number of core and for example the size of raster to deal with ?